# c search in array of generic type

Tags: c, arrays, search

I have 2 structs,

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short id;
    char name[10];
    char email[10];
} foo;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned short id;
    char test[10];
    float ok;
} bar;
```

and I need to create a *reusable* function/procedure that search for a value in two arrays of these struct.

Here's my function:

```
short search_array(const int *array, const int dim, int query)
{
    short idx = -1;

    if (query >= 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        {
            /*
             * since array is a generic pointer,
             * take:
             *  pointer to the position array+ i
             *  convert the value to unsigned short
             *  finally get final value of short
             */
            if ((*(unsigned short *) (array + i)) == query)
            {
                idx = i;
                i = dim;
            }
        }
    }

    return idx;
}
```

Here's my main:

```
int main()
{
    foo a = {10, "ok", "pippo"};
    foo b = {50, "si", "gino"};
    foo c = {30, "si", "peppo"};

    foo foos[3] = {a, b, c};

    bar a1 = {6, "mario", 5.5};
    bar b2 = {56, "mimmo", 0};
    bar c3 = {69, "maronno", 9};

    bar bars[3] = {a1, b2, c3};

    int x = search_array((const int *) foos, 3, 50);
    int x1 = search_array((const int *) foos, 3, 9999999);

    int y = search_array((const int *) bars, 3, 69);
    int y1 = search_array((const int *) bars, 3, 9999999);

    return 0;
}
```

It works for `foo` struct if I change the signature of the function to:

```
short search_array(const foo *array, const int dim, int query)
```

and calling method to:

```
int x = search_array(foos, 3, 30);
```

but not for `bar` struct and viceversa.

My goal is to create a single function/procedure and no code duplication by using pointer arithmetic.
I think that generic types don't exist in C, so I thought that I can use the size of my struct to use pointer arithmetic. Help if it is possible?

Comment: If it doesn't matter that array will be sorted, you could simply use `bsearch` (and optionally `qsort`) from standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to pass the size of the structure into the function, and do pointer arithmetic on `char`-sized units:

```
short search_array(const void *array, const int dim, const int item_size, int query)
{
    short idx = -1;

    if (query >= 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        {
            /*
             * since array is a generic pointer,
             * take:
             *  pointer to the position array+ i
             *  convert the value to unsigned short
             *  finally get final value of short
             */
            if ((*(unsigned short *) ((const char*)array + i * item_size)) == query)
            {
                idx = i;
                i = dim;
            }
        }
    }

    return idx;
}


int main()
{
    foo a = {10, "ok", "pippo"};
    foo b = {50, "si", "gino"};
    foo c = {30, "si", "peppo"};

    foo foos[3] = {a, b, c};

    bar a1 = {6, "mario", 5.5};
    bar b2 = {56, "mimmo", 0};
    bar c3 = {69, "maronno", 9};

    bar bars[3] = {a1, b2, c3};

    int x = search_array(foos, 3, sizeof foos[0], 50);
    int x1 = search_array(foos, 3, sizeof foos[0], 9999999);

    int y = search_array(bars, 3, sizeof bars[0], 69);
    int y1 = search_array(bars, 3, sizeof bars[0], 9999999);

    return 0;
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70566dc1356b32fe)

---

Side note: you're passing the array size as `int`, but the index into the array as `short`. These types should match, otherwise your code will break for arrays whose size doesn't fit into a `short`.

Likewise, the parameter `query` should be of type `unsigned short` rather than `int`, as that's what is actually stored in the structures.

Comment: Thanks; now I changed my function params to `size_t dim` and `unsigned short query`. 2 questions: can I use `sizeof(foo)` instead of `sizeof(foos[0])`? why are you using `char`-sized units? is it because char size is 1?

Comment: @user3744384 Yes, you can of course use `sizeof(foo)` too. I chose `sizeof foos[0]` to make it future-proof wrt. changes of the type of `foos`. To the second question: since `sizeof` values are in units of `char`, you need to do size-based pointer arithmetic (as opposed to item-based pointer arithmetic) on `char*`.